# Trying to identify used pattern/paradigm (using C#)

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

While working on a particular design for a object heirarchy I came up with a situation, and built a design that works, but it's pretty confusing pattern in use, and I wanted to check if anyone had seen this pattern before and if there was any literature on it:

So imagine you have a Heirarchy of Animals:

```
class Animal
class Mammal : Animal
class Dolphin : Mammal
```

Now imagine we have an interface:

```
interface IMating<T>
{
    MateWith(T otherAnimal);
}
```

In this instance I'm using generics to strongly type the `MateWith` method. I could just use object and do some casting which could be unsafe, but I chose to strongly type things.

Given this interface what I ideally would want is:

```
class Animal : IMating<Animal>
{
}

class Mammal : Animal, IMating<Mammal>
{
}

class Dolphin : Mammal, IMating<Dolphin>
{
}
```

Doing this allows the derived `IMating.MateWith` method to extend it's parents behavior by use the base versions of these classes. Of course this means if I were to use an instance of `Dolphin` I would land up with the following methods on `Dolphin`:

```
Dolphin.MateWith(Animal a);
Dolphin.MateWith(Mammal m);
Dolphin.MateWith(Dolphin d);
```

Obviously I only want the last method in that list, and I want the others hidden from access and just used up the base chain (Animal and mammal are not abstract in my case and can be instantiated). One alternative is to make use of composition thus abstracting the inner "base" class under use.

Since this felt more like a heirarchy that lends itself to inheritance I solved my problem using generic constraints as follows (with some side effects):

```
class Animal<T> : IMating<T>
where T : Animal
{
}

class Mammal<T> : Animal<T>
where T : Mammal
{
}

class Dolphin<T> : Mammal<T>
where T : Dolphin
{
}
```

Basically I'm making each class in heirarchy generic but at mininum the type parameter must be at least of the type of the class itself or any derived version of that class.

The pattern for the most part solves what I'm trying to achieve, but I'm wondering if this kind of pattern is used anywhere else and what for? Is it documented somewhere? Is it well known?

Thanks in advance for any help/pointers

Comment: I don't know what the pattern is called.  But your structure makes sense to me.

Comment: Also, I'm sure your _real_ usage is different that what you post, but in your case I'd expect the `IMating` interface to _only_ be applied at the `Dolphin` level, since in reality, a mammal does not mate with any other arbitrary mammal.  Perhaps that applies to your real usage as well?

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx which uses examples similar to your own.

Comment: I'm still not sure the structure makes sense.  In your case `class Dog : Animal<Cat>` would be a valid type.

Comment: @DStanley yeah my mating example is a little confusing but in the real scenario, which is a little more complex for just showing the point definitely the Mammal can mate with another arbitrary mammal

Comment: @LukeH thanks exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @DStanley yeah in case you mentioned it doesn't make sense and that's one of the pitfalls of curiously repeating template pattern is you can do something like this to shot yourself in foot